# How do I go about merging multiple varchar columns into 1 based on id value - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to merge multiple rows in a column (Actions) into one row for each Form_id value and want the output to contain the following columns:

```
FORM_ID, 
DATE_CREATED,
ACTIONS
```

Data example is for one FORM_ID value only:

```
FORM_ID DATE_CREATED                    ACTIONS
382953  2015-07-06 00:00:00.0000000     Spoke with Vicky 
382953  2015-07-07 00:00:00.0000000     Email received from Charlie Casa Mon 
382953  2015-07-09 00:00:00.0000000     Email received from Charlie Casa Tues
```

My intention is to have entries in the actions column merged into one row with each entry seperated by comma ', ' as illustrated below example:

```
FORM_ID     DATE_CREATED                        ACTIONS
382953      2015-07-06 00:00:00.0000000         Spoke with Vicky, Email received from Charlie Casa Mon, Email received from Charlie Casa Mon
```

The following ddl example of the table and it's data types and values:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GSL_FEEDBACK_ACTIONS]
(
    [ACTIONS] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [ACTION_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [ACTION_TYPE_NAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CUST_CONTACTED] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [DATE_CREATED] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [FORM_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [PERFORMED_BY] [varchar](80) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In Oracle I can use the `Listagg` function, but I'm having difficulty in SQL  Server. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If I'm unable to resolve this on SQL, I might look into doing the same task in Oracle before the data is imported into SQL instance over the Linked Server.

Thanks for your help.

Cheers.

Solution found:

```
select distinct form_id, STUFF(( select distinct ', '+ ACTIONS from dbo.GSL_FEEDBACK_ACTION a where b.form_id = a.form_id FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1 ,1, '') Members from dbo.GSL_FEEDBACK_ACTION b where FORM_ID = 382953;
```

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use stuff( xml path()) and Felix is right, this is a duplicate question

Comment: @Craig, can you post the expected results based on your sample data?

Comment: Raffaello, thanks for the response I'll check out the duplicate post in regards to the STUFF function.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Thanks for the follow up mate, I've updated my notes to include the expected results, just above the table ddl.
Cheers.

Comment: @Craig, it's clearly a duplicate. Have you tried the answer on the link?

Comment: @FelixPamittan - not yet mate, new to seeking help on blogs.  Just checking the link out now.  Looks straight forward, will give a go.
Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Pamittan  Got it sorted with the following syntax.

    ' select distinct form_id, STUFF(( select distinct ', '+ ACTIONS from dbo.GSL_FEEDBACK_ACTION a
where b.form_id = a.form_id FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1 ,1, '') Members
from dbo.GSL_FEEDBACK_ACTION b
--group by FORM_ID;
where FORM_ID = 382953; '

Thanks for your help.

Cheers.